# How can i change the negative numbers to 0 from my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert or disable the negative numbers to 0 on my

[Website](http://nutrinet.hol.es/nutrinet/?q=node/133) which appear when i select some products on the column 'Unidad Minima'    and 'Unidad Maxima'for example 10 or more for each one.

I've tried by using the [format number jquery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/)  but it didn't work in this case.

There is some code from my webpage.

```
$("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
    var $val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
    cantidadesminimas = (8260 - cantidadfinal) / $val3;
    cantidadesmaximas = (12390 - cantidadfinal) / $val3;

    $('.val5', this).html(cantidadesminimas.toFixed(0));
    $('.val6', this).html(cantidadesmaximas.toFixed(0));
});

$("#cantidadmin").html(8260 - cantidadfinal.toFixed(0));
$("#cantidadmax").html(12390 - cantidadfinal.toFixed(0));
```

}

Some comment will be apreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try `function negToZero(x){ if (x<0) return 0; }`, Should work, but it is untested.

Comment: Ignore that, that was terrible code, my bad... Should be:  `function negToZero(x){return (x<0) ? 0 : x}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the short if else like this:

```
$('.val5', this).html((cantidadesminimas < 0 ? 0 : cantidadesminimas));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built in Math.max(x, 0) method. The result will be which ever is highest, your input or zero.

e.g.

```
var x = -1;
var a = Math.max(x, 0);
```

If 'x' is negative 'a' will be zero else 'a' will be equal to 'x'.

Comment: Thank you bhspencer, but the other code was easier to me to introduce.